# Не могу создать EntityManager с параметром JTA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Пытаюсь создать правильные  DAO и для этого все абстрагирую. И почти вышло но есть проблема. Чтобы сделать persist мне нужно открыть транзакцию а потом ее закрыть. Я прочитал что это решается тем что меняется `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` на `transaction-type="JTA"`. Это должно избавить меня от ручного открытия и закрытия транзакций. Но когда я меняю это свойство, то мой `EntityManager`  перестает создаваться. А создаю я его так

```
public abstract class BaseJpaDao<E> implements BaseDao<E> {

    protected Class<?> entityClass;

    private EntityManager em;

    public BaseJpaDao(Class<?> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("COLIBRI").createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

что я делаю не так? или какие есть способы создать этот `EntityManager`?

я использую  javaEE  а не  Spring  поэтому такие проблемы. тут аннотации не работают типа `@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "test")` и тд. Они работают только если класс является  `EJB` а у меня обычные  DAO классы.

Comment: Ну так и JTA работает без ручного вмешательства только в EJB. В остальных случаях внедряется `@Resource UserTransaction ut; ...` и далее по накатанной схеме `ut.begin(); ... ut.commit();`:) `EntityManager` внедряется так `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "COLIBRI") private EntityManager em;` Почитайте литературку внимательней, всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь следует понимать, что Spring и JavaEE имеют разное представление о том, какими baen-ами и как они управляют.
Ваш DAO переселенный из Spring в JavaEE без каких-либо дополнительных телодвижений этот самый JavaEE попросту не заметит. Никаких экземпляров не будет даже попытки создать и естественно никакие аннотации на нём никогда не сработают.
Ваши Spring DAO надо переделывать, что бы JavaEE признал их как родных.
В Вашем вопросе не видно никаких даже намёков, что из себя представляет Ваш DAO с точки зрения JavaEE. (Точнее видно, что для JavaEE он никакого интереса не представляет, не являясь ни ejb, ни cdi, ни чем-то ещё полезным JavaEE)
Как уже отметил в комментарии, JTA автоматически начинает и заканчивается только в EJB. В противном случае надо получить `UserTransaction` от контейнера и на нём вручную вызывать `begin`, `commt` и всё остальное, что обычно делают с транзакциями.
Необходимо так же определиться какой будет persistence context: Container Managed или Application Managed. От этого зависит кое-что. В том числе необходимость выполнить какие-то шаги для участия в транзакции JTA.
Попытка создать фабрику как бы намекает на Application managed persistent context. А раз он Application managed, то неудивительно, что аннотации внедрения (@persistenceUnit) не работают как кому-то хочется.